# Observable validate each item

Tags: exception, rx-java, rx-java2

How to validate each item in `Observable` and return an error if condition failed?
Now I'm using `switchMap` with `if` inside, but this solution looks not very nice:

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, -1, 4)
    .switchMap(x -> {
        if (x >= 0) {
            return Observable.just(x);
        } else {
            return Observable.error(new Exception("Input value should be positive"));
        }
    })
    .subscribe(
        x -> System.out.printf("value=%d\n", x),
        err -> System.out.printf("error: %s\n", err.getMessage())
    );
```

Can I use any built-in method instead of this?

Comment: isn't it a filter?

Comment: @PhoenixWang `filter` just drops "bad" values, whereas I need an exception

Comment: 1. you could just throws an exception in filter and the operator will deliver the error. 2. I think that's not good implementation for a reactive stream. An exception means you can not listen/subscribe to the stream anymore. You better use a ErrorState instead of Exception. For example, Result<T> that contain your value or exception to indicate the validate result. @g4s8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`doOnNext()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html) to throw your exception.

```
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, -1, 4)
        .doOnNext(x -> {
            if (x < 0) throw Exception("Input value should be positive");
        })
        .subscribe(
            x -> System.out.printf("value=%d\n", x),
            err -> System.out.printf("error: %s\n", err.message)
        );
```